# Ransack association search breaking after upgrading rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemodel, ransack

I have a model, `Student`, that with a habtm relationship with another model, `Group`. The following code:

```
Student.ransack(groups_id_eq: 22839).result
```

Produces the following SQL:

```
SELECT "students".* FROM "students" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "groups_students" ON "groups_students"."student_id" = "students"."id" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "groups" ON "groups"."id" = "groups_students"."group_id" 
WHERE "groups"."id" = NULL
```

Notice that it's converting `22839` into `NULL`

This was working before upgrading to rails 5.

I have another model, `User`, with the same habtm relationship with groups. When I try `Student.ransack(groups_id_eq: 22839).result` it works and produces the desired SQL. The difference between two models is that `Student` has a uuid id, whereas `User`

Edit: This does appear to be a bug and I've submitted an [issue](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/issues/786) with a more comprehensive [gist](https://gist.github.com/wefarrell/d0c16e5eb372bc7365a94f6b11261f74).

Comment: There are some issues with this gist. I tried to run it, but it failed while creating `students` table, because of default value. I've changed the code to generate uuid in AR callback. After that the code works as expected. Tests are passing and generated sql looks ok.

Comment: Can you create a gist and put it here?

Comment: According to the github issue you already resolved the issue, is that true or is your question here still valid?

Comment: Yes, I will post an answer. Thank you for noticing @BoraMa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by monkey patching ActiveRecord AliasTracker.

See my [gh issue](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/issues/786) for the full explanation.